# Not able to send print funtion output to file and geeting error during execution

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I need to send print function output to file but i am  getting error please help.

My script:

```
  #get time for to create log file
  timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

  ## Open the file with read only permit
  f = open ('file1', 'r')

  ## Read the first line 
  line = f.readline()

  ## If the file is not empty keep reading line one at a time
  ## till the file is empty
  while line:
  print timestamp
  ip,owner = line.split()
  print ip
  logfile = ("log-" + timestamp)
  print('###################################    ' + ip + ' logs') >>logfile
  print logfile
  FNULL = open(logfile, 'a')
  sshconnection = subprocess.call(["ssh", ip, "uptime"], stdout=FNULL,      stderr=FNULL, shell=False)
  if sshconnection == 0:
   print('Connection Established to Remote Host ' + ip)
  else:
   print('Please check the Remote Host Reachable or Password less  configured' + ip)
  print owner
  newpassword()
```

After code execution I am getting below error:

```
 print('###################################    ' + ip + ' logs       ####################################') >> logfile
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'str' and 'str'
```

I am using python2.7

Comment: Why are you using `>>`? This is not like C, in Python that's the bit shift operator used on integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to a file like this in Python. You should do this instead :

```
f = open(logfile,'w')
f.write("##########################       {}   logs\n".format(ip)) 
f.close()
```

Comment: You can, actually, but the OP got the order mixed up.

Comment: If you are writing to a file, you'll need to explicitly add a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the Unix `>>` symbol for appending to a file within Python.

In Python `>>` is a bitwise operator that expects two integers as operands (`x >> y` returns `x` with the bits shifted to the right by `y` places).

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how `>>` redirection operator. In Python 2, the [`print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) does support redirection, but you have to put it *before* the expression producing the print value, and you need to *open the file* first:

```
with open(logfile, 'a') as log:
    print >> log, '###################################    ' + ip + ' logs'
```

Note that the `print` statement *is not a function*, and doesn't take parentheses.

You can use the Python 3 compatible [`print()` *function*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) in Python 2, but you need to use the following import statement at the top:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

after which you'd use the `file` argument:

```
with open(logfile, 'a') as log:
    print('###################################    ' + ip + ' logs', file=logfile)
```

You may want to look at using [string formatting with `str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to interpolate data into a string:

```
with open(logfile, 'a') as log:
    print('###################################    {} logs'.format(ip), file=logfile)
```

You can also write directly to the file, but do remember to add a newline explicitly:

```
with open(logfile, 'a') as log:
    log.write('###################################    {} logs\n'.format(ip))
```

Note the `\n` at the end of the string template there.